# How do you not send a user agent with Paw?

Tags: paw-app

By default, Paw will send a user agent identifying itself as Paw.

I know you can set the user agent field manually to override this and send a different value.

However, how do you not send the user agent at all? (I.e. not empty but actually not in the headers)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible at this point. Paw will always send a minimum of 3 headers: Connection, Host and User-Agent. Though, I can see that in some cases, it would be nice to try without. I'll take that as a feature request and add this on our todo list. Thanks!